# Trying to create an overview or summary sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm hoping there is a way to do this that I am unaware of, but long story short I have created a work book for forecasting labor needs for all of our jobsites over the next few weeks.  I have each jobsite on its own sheet within the book and I am trying to add an overview sheet at the front for a quick glance. I was able to pull the raw data in and sum it using SUM(sheet1!b1, sheet2!b1,etc.) but I would really like a way to add a cell that pulls in the sheet names of every sheet that actually has values since this book will include both jobs that are winding down and don't have people on site every day as well as jobs that haven't started up yet.  I'm sure there is a way to do this with a database but that seems like severe overkill for this problem.

I tried googling but didn't see anything relevant likely because I didn't recognize the solution under my nose.

Just for clarity the function I am looking for is a way to create a list of sheet names consisting only of the sheets that contain a value within certain cells I tried `=IF(SUM(sheet1!A1:A3)>0,"sheet1",)` which works fine, but I need to test for and print the name of every sheet which meets this condition and it won't let me just create a string of IF statements as a list.

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The question has no references to your situation other than `Sheet1!B1` and `Sheet2!B1`, this is what would only sum the B1 cells that have data in them:
`=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet2!B1)`

Where `Sheet1` is the first sheet containing your data and `Sheet2` is the last sheet containing data. Change `Sheet2` to the last sheet name you would like to include in the sum*.

Caveat: it is important that the first up to the last sheet referenced don't have sheets in between that hold different info and need not be summed along.

*Technically it also sums the cells without data, but these are summed as `0`.

[image]